# Azure Session State It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s)

Tags: azure, session-state

I did all the steps from this tutorial (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)

- Created new MVC Web Site
- Added Nuget package
- Modified the Web.Config to reflect my Azure Redis

But, everytime i try to run my project, i get the following error message :

It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked that the required TCP ports are open on your local firewall (6380 and 6379)? If not the connections will fail.

Comment: Two more ways this can fail. If you download an old sample (like my MVC movie  cache sample) you must first remove the old NugGet Redis package, then add the current version. Another way this can fail is if you add a trailing space to the host= URL section, that's an easy mistake to make with copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

By default, non-ssl port 6379 is disable for azure redis cache. Use ssl = "true" in web.config and everything should work fine.

If you don't want to use SSL then go to https://portal.azure.com and for you redis cache enable non-ssl port by going through Settings -> Access Ports -> Allow access only via SSL and click on "NO" and save.

Recommended and secure way is to use SSL.

Comment: Just tested. I was able to repro the error by adding an extra trailing space in the host= URL